# Java : Equals() does not compare right

Tags: java, string, compare, equals

if I was not really stuck I wouldnt post here. I am trying to compare 2 Strings with equals(), sadly it never goes through the if function.
here is the code :

```
 public ListElement searchElement(String o) {
        ListElement le = first;
        while (le != null) {
            System.out.println("NAME : " + le.getName() + " : " + o + " " + le.getName().equals(o));
            if (le.getName().equals(o))
            {                               
                return le;
            }
            le = le.next;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

and here is the output :

```
NAME : aa : aa   false
NAME : cc : aa   false
NAME : bb : aa   false
NAME : aa : bb   false
NAME : cc : bb   false
NAME : bb : bb   false
NAME : aa : cc   false
NAME : cc : cc   false
NAME : bb : cc   false
NAME : aa : aa   false
NAME : cc : aa   false
NAME : bb : aa   false
NAME : aa : bb   false
NAME : cc : bb   false
NAME : bb : bb   false
NAME : aa : cc   false
NAME : cc : cc   false
```

Every time I compare 2 equal String, the programm does not see it. Any hints please ?

Comment: As per output there is one extra space in String `o` in the end. Try after trimming `le.getName().trim().equals(o.trim())`. better to trim both before compare.

Comment: Tip: When I'm debugging and I need to dump `String`s, I usually put something around them, like `|`'s or `"`'s or something else visible, to make it obvious when there are extra spaces at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: I am sorry. It was so easy. Yet I spent an hour to solve that.
I should indeed use " | " as marquer, in order to count the empty space.

Comment: You must learn how to debug code?

Comment: first you can check the length as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each second string has two extra spaces at the end; this can be resolved by changing `le.getName().equals(o)` to `le.getName().equals(o.trim())`. The `trim()` method in `String` gets rid of any extra spaces at the beginning or end of the given string.

Comment: there might be `name` have trailing spaces as well.

Comment: In this example there aren't any trailing spaces on `le.getName()`, though for future reference it would be useful to trim both.